# Content That Changes width with animated sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, sidebar

I am making a website containing a main content holder, and have added a sidebar to the left to activate on hover, how would i get about changing the main contents width for when the sidebar is used and by doing so move the content inside it dynamically.

Here is the code i have so far for my sidebar

`$(function(){
    $('#nav').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'200px'},500);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'35px'},500);
    }).trigger('mouseleave');
});`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about sidebar but I found this site http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/ using   http://www.google.com . I hope it help.